# Recursive model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a trouble trying to get this working.  I have an Item model, and each Item can have other items or nothing.

So is this possible or do I need to do some magic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either use the [acts as tree plugin](http://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree/tree/master) or build it your self:

```
belongs_to                :parent,
                          :foreign_key => "parent_id",
                          :class_name => "Item"

has_many                  :children,
                          :foreign_key => 'parent_id',
                          :class_name => 'Item',
                          :order => 'created_at ASC',
                          :dependent => :delete_all
```

Comment: AN alternative to a_a_tree is acts_as_nested_set which has much better performance for read operations.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [self-referential association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association).

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some AR builtins or libs plugins / gems to handle most non-bizarre use cases, but: Not clear if you're talking about a

- join table / Actve record association, (heterogeneous relationsip, 2 or three tables)
- nested set / acts_as_tree, (tree of like objects in one table) or
- Single table inheritance, somewhat heterogeneous objects in one table

or, the messiest thing, a
- Entity-Attribute-Value table (EAV) design

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-Attribute-Value_model